# ¿Cómo variar tres variables en una tabla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero saber cuantos tiempos un elemento fue en un intervalo de confianza, que muevo también por consiguiente :

```
prices_well_predicted = len([x for x in prediction if x in range(lower,upper) for lower,upper in low_CI,upper_CI])
```

Intento también:

```
prices_well_predicted = len([x for x,lower,upper in prediction,low_CI,upper_CI if x in range(lower,upper)])
```

Pero ambos me dan `SyntaxError`.

#### Adjuntos:

El contexto está predicciones que traze con CI, el intervalo de confianza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí los datos son :

prediction :

```
[17294.9 17424.2 17465.7 17348.8 17345.8 17037.4 16783.  17067.8 17194.
 16655.8 17035.8 16839.2 16829.9 16437.1 16561.1 16641.  16793.7 16366.3
 16486.6 16722.  16142.6 17098.2 16608.9 16320.8 15979.2 16328.1 16672.4
 16470.4 16536.2 17320.7 16940.8 16595.1 16469.4 16682.7 16443.2 16619.8
 16308.8 16355.7 16409.7 16570.4 16174.9 16327.7 16594.8 17177.1 17304.8
 17217.6 17064.4 17042.5 16818.5 17293.2 16689.3 17099.6 16870.1 16623.1
 17386.8 16928.2 17002.4 17096.2 16745.8 16609.5 17055.7 16974.7 17354.4
 17205.  17178.7 17185.1 16966.6 17021.4 17062.3 17238.6 17263.3 17339.3
 17455.5 17327.4 17155.1 16824.8 17617.4 17505.7 17709.1 17646.1 17715.1
 17008.4 17572.4 17604.8 17815.4 17682.7 17775.5 17726.2 17950.8 17781.6
 17504.7 17586.3 17906.2 17640.2 17865.8 17624.9 17579.6 17657.4 17778.5
 17578.2 17850.7 17752.1 17199.5 18018.3 18059.1 17525.7 17930.6 17991.3
 18032.2 18124.7 17717.3 17623.7 17871.  17956.6 17611.5 18014.  18018.8
 17736.  17537.3 17690.9 17880.5 17906.1 17960.1 17976.  17925.6 17611.3
 17703.5 17603.8 17820.5 17815.8 17838.2 17622.2 17616.6 17574.3 17852.5
 17644.8 17581.2 17452.9 17887.  17439.8 17733.5 17401.7 17799.9 17619.9
 17375.  17696.6 17867.1 17156.4 17847.6 17773.4 17376.8 17882.4 17945.
 17565.4 17699.5 17985.9 18144.  18100.6 17896.6 17978.6 17872.1 17618.4
 17946.2 17824.7 17863.4 17541.2 17776.4 17675.5 17460.5 17746.1 17923.5
 17604.  17418.8 17715.7 18074.6 17484.4 17403.9 17327.6 17419.6 17937.6
 17734.7 17202.7 17957.8 17967.6 18173.7 17867.6 17364.5 17817.1 17705.
 18081.5 18244.3 18158.4 18071.8 17759.6 18055.3 18291.7 18322.6 18300.9
 18343.  18230.2 18555.8 17537.3 18175.4 18249.  18408.3 18011.6 18393.1
 18296.9 18152.4 17625.  18184.5 18358.4 17681.3 17977.5 18018.9 18228.5
 17342.  18301.3 18410.8 18255.2 18330.5 18092.3 18442.2 18281.9 18502.4
 17891.7 18272.3 18602.3 18480.2 18066.9 17654.3 18395.6 18162.8 18322.3
 18427.  18329.3 18162.2 18046.9 18085.8 17964.4 18206.7 18098.6 18074.6
 18217.7 17692.4 18346.3 18090.1 17954.  18466.6 18376.4 18254.4 18184.6
 17866.  17591.4 17986.5 18168.5 18177.1 18028.8 18214.2 17910.2 18085.6
 17995.2 18022.  18137.7 17706.2 17937.6 17548.7 17641.9 18071.9 18063.8
 17866.3 17073.  18155.8 18098.8 18142.  18173.6 17774.7 18179.6 17931.2
 18153.  18101.1 17170.4 18317.6 18424.3 18063.6 18246.6 18189.1 17503.1
 17853.9 17967.6 17858.5 17945.  18165.4 17944.4 18056.3 18196.1 17753.7
 18201.8 18208.5 18100.  17774.3 18045.9 17781.4 18163.1 18104.7]
```

y

```
low_CI = 0.95*prediction
upper_CI = 1.05*prediction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que `prediction` es la lista de floats que nos muestras.

He intentado reproducir el problema. He parseado la lista (copiándola y pegándola mediante `""" """` y la he convertido a una lista de floats:

```
str = """17294.9 17424.2 17465.7 17348.8 17345.8 17037.4 16783.  17067.8 17194.
16655.8 17035.8 16839.2 16829.9 16437.1 16561.1 16641.  16793.7 16366.3
...
"""
arr = str.split(' ')
prediction = [float(f) for f in arr if f]
```

Pero tanto `low_CI` como `upper_CI` no tienen sentido en este caso. Supongo que lo que aparece como código es la fómula matemática que quieres aplicar, pero no el código en si, esto es:

```
low_CI = [0.95 * p for p in prediction]
upper_CI = [1.05 * p for p in prediction]
```

Realmente creo que falta la lista de precios, pero teniéndola podrías hacerlo así, asumiendo que price es la lista de precios, que tiene igual tamaño que la lista de predicciones y que los índices entre precios y predicciones coinciden, puedes usar enumerate [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) [uses](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) para acceder a cada precio junto con su índice, de forma que lo puedas relacionar con la predicción de ese precio, y con los márgenes de tolerancia inferior y superior:

```
prices_well_predicted = len([p for i, p in enumerate(price) if low_CI[i] <= p and p <= upper_CI[i]])
```

Es más, realmente no necesitas construir `low_CI` ni `upper_CI`:

```
prices_well_predicted = len([p for i, p in enumerate(price) if 0.95 * prediction[i] <= p and p <= 1.05 * prediction[i]])
```

Con esto tendrías cuántas veces la predicción es correcta con un margen de error del 5%.